US 50s,60s, or maybe 70s movie/tv-movie about adulterous businessman who makes frequent business trips
Calling Mrs John Dobson ...
(Hopefully I remembered the name correctly.)
Mr John Dobson is a businessman who makes many business trips often flying off to different cities in the USofA.  Although he is married to a devoted and loving wife, he is having an adulterous affair with his secretary.
To make more time together to pursue his affair, he pretends to be going on an unexpected business trip and gets his secretary to accompany him to the airport (for a realistic sound background) and she pretends to be a Bell Telephone Operator calling his wife to initiate a person to person telephone call (from some distant city) and then passes the phone to him so that he can then explain that je will not be home but has been called away on business for several days.  This she does in an official manner by starting the call to his wife with the line "Calling Mrs John Dobson'.  Then they both head off to a motel for the next couple of days (weekend?).
As this works so well, the plan gets repeated on several occasions.  Then for some reason, his secretary has to call at the businessman's home to get something for him which had had forgotten. During the conversation with his wife who is at home. the wife recognises that the voice of his secretary is the same as the supposed telephone operator who always says "Calling Mrs John Dobson" accompanied by the message frome her husband having to go away for for a few days, and so the sordid affair is exposed.
I have done numerous searches including IMDB which come up blank and even asked on a classic movie forum but got no clues other than it may have been a made for tv movie.
